# PHP MYSQL Compare rows when defining WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, compare, where-clause

Lets say I have these DB rows

```
id | storage | used | status
1  -   100   -  0   -    1
2  -   1000  - 5000 -    1
```

I need to compare the rows "storage" and "used"

I want to select rows WHERE status = 1 and Column"storage" > Column"used".

I tried WHERE status = '1' AND storage > used

It should report back row id #1, but it doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `WHERE status=1 AND storage > used` is correct. If you tried it and didn't get back the row with `id=1` there's something wrong with your data.

Are `storage` and `used` numeric columns? Or are they stored as a `VARCHAR` (or, *gasp*, `TEXT`)? If so, you won't be able to compare them quite the way you want, and will first have to convert or cast them to numeric types. It would be better to change the type to actually be numeric (i.e., `INT` or `DECIMAL` or whichever other type is appropriate).

Comment: nvm i know where i failed... forgot to fetch array. lol k thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE status = '1' AND storage > used
```

should give you the right solution, like VoteyDisciple mentioned, make sure `status` and `used` are both of numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SELECT * FROM`table`WHERE status = '1' AND storage > used` but the data type of the storage and used must be NUMERIC not VARCHAR.

if Still you didn't get correct ans then it should be problem with your data storage structure.

Thanks!